# Why isn't my parent component re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a parent component which renders a list of child components. This list is taken from the redux store.

In each child component, I have a delete button to delete that particular item from the redux store and hence also delete that child component.

My child component deletes the item from the store fine, so how come my parent components isn't re-rendered to have that child removed from the list??

I've tried setting a "refresh" local state in the parent component and attempting to toggle that in the child component, but that didn't work for some reason..

Here's my parent component:

```
class TodaysClasses extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchTodayClasses('Tuesday')
  }

  renderClasses = (classes) => {
    if (classes.length > 0) {
      return classes.map((classRoom) => {
        return (
          <ClassComp classId={classRoom.id} key={classRoom.id}
            deleteClass={this.props.deleteClass}
          />
        )
      })
    } else {
      return <div>There are no classes for today.</div>
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Todays Classes</h3>
        <div className="ui divider"></div>
        <div className="ui grid container">
          <div className="row">
            {this.renderClasses(this.props.classes)}
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <Link to="/newclass" className="ui labeled primary icon button">
              <i className="plus icon" />
              Add Class
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  // turn the classes object to an array for easier iterations
  return { classes: Object.values(state.classes) }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchTodayClasses, deleteClass })(TodaysClasses)
```

And here's my child component:

```
const ClassComp = (props) => {
  const { teacher, subject, students, id } = props.classOf

  return (
    <div className="ui segment" >
      <div className="content">
        <div className="ui medium header">{teacher} - {subject}</div>
        <div className="ui divider"></div>
        <div className="ui sub header">Students</div>
        <div>{renderStudents(students)}</div>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: '30px' }}>
          <button className="mini compact ui negative right floated button"
            onClick={() => props.deleteClass(id)}>Delete Class
          </button>
          <button className="mini compact ui right floated button">Edit Class</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div >
  )
}


const renderStudents = (students) => {
  if (students && students.length > 0) {
    return (
      <ol>
        {students.map((student, index) =>
          <li key={index}>{student}</li>
        )}
      </ol>
    )
  } else {
    return <p style={{ margin: '10px' }} >No students registered.</p>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { classOf: state.classes[ownProps.classId] }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ClassComp)
```

Here are my action creators:

```
export const fetchTodayClasses = day => async dispatch => {
  const response = await classes.get(`/classes?day=${day}`)

  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_TODAYCLASSES', payload: response.data })
}
```

and

```
export const deleteClass = id => async dispatch => {
  await classes.delete(`/classes/${id}`)

  dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_CLASS', payload: id })
}
```

and here's my reducer:

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {    
    case 'DELETE-CLASS':
      return _.omit(state, action.payload)
    case 'FETCH_TODAYCLASSES':
      return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, 'id') }    
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: What does fetchTodayClasses do? I suggest that you post your action creator and reducer code, too.

Comment: Are you creating a new instance of your collection when delete? Or are you modifying the existing collection? My gut feeling is that you are mutating state incorrectly

Comment: I've added my action creators and reducers.

I believe I'm mutating the state correctly, as you can see I'm using the omit function from lodash to do it.

Comment: Maybe I need another lifecycle method in the parent component? Something like componentDidUpdate() ? I'm not sure how to use it though..

Comment: I don't suppose you could replicate the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: I have a small back-end set up and I just don't know how to set that up in fiddle. 

Would you be able to tell me though, if my approach is wrong..? I am getting a list of items from my store, and for each item I am rendering a child component. I want each child component to be able to delete itself, and cause a render of the parent component without that deleted child. 

My delete action works fine, I see it firing in the redux log as well in the server log, however I have to manually refresh the page to see it removed....

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a step when you delete an item:

1. An action of type DELETE-CLASS dispatched
2. the item gets deleted by the reducer
3. **missing step** - update the store with the new data

You can achieve it via 2 common patterns:

1. Get a new array via API call

   ```
   componentDidUpdated() {
       this.props.actions.fetchTodayClasses(DAY);
   }
   ```
2. Update the array within a reducer ([redux mutation patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns))

   ```
    case 'DELETE-CLASS':
      let updatedClasses = _.omit(state, action.payload);
      return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(updatedClasses, 'id') }
   ```

   I think these two options are the most common patterns in react-redux. You check this [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6zn18j228r) to watch the demo. Make sure you use it correctly with your state structure.

Comment: OMG! I just realised and fixed my issue after your comment! If you notice as well, my action type is "DELETE_CLASS" whereas my reducer was checking for "DELETE-CLASS" with hyphen instead of an underscore..!
Just goes to show that I should have exported my action types in an actionTypes.js file! Thank you!

Comment: Great news! If you want to avoid this in the future, make sure that you keep your action types in a separate file and export them. So you wont need to hard-code them as a string in many places and just import the types and use them wherever you need.